# Prevent CSS classes from being overridden

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a project that uses JQuery-UI. I recently found formee, which is a nice framework for building forms. One annoyance is that the formee submit button styling overrides the jquery-ui themed button style. How can I get all of the formee goodness but keep my jquery-ui button style? I realize I can edit the formee CSS to remove the button style, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Haven't tested this (which is why it isn't an answer), but what about including the jUI css after the formee css?

Comment: @SenorAmor: that's already the case actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as you said yourself, remove the offending CSS, which is what I would recommend.

Alternatively you can give the jQuery UI css classes that apply on the relevant button [more specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the formee classes. This would be second best solution.

As a last case you could add `!important;` behind all CSS attributes in the classes for jQuery UI... I really wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: +1 for both mentioning and linking to specificity, and suggesting them before the sledgehammer of `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

use this to bring front:

```
#your-div-id{
   position:relative;
   z-index:999999;
}
```